# Create ID based on conditions from another column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to create unique IDs based on some conditions, but I really do not know how to get this the way I expect.

I've got two important columns "Concepto" (Concept) and ID (which is where I wanna carry out the transformation and it's a duplicate of Concepto. The table is as follows:

| Concepto | ID |
| --- | --- |
| TARJETA ENT: REF:08780807807 8603CDTO. BUSINESS 1040-25/12/2021 | TARJETA ENT: REF:08780807807 8603CDTO. BUSINESS 1040-25/12/2021 |
| TARJETA ENT:-REF:08780810810 8603CDTO. BUSINESS 1040-25/12/2021 | TARJETA ENT:-REF:08780810810 8603CDTO. BUSINESS 1040-25/12/2021 |
| INTERESES DE PRESTAMO PTMO.:000087816490219968 | INTERESES DE PRESTAMO PTMO.:000087816490219968 |
| AMORTIZACION PRESTAMO PTMO.:000087816490219968 | AMORTIZACION PRESTAMO PTMO.:000087816490219968 |
| INTERESES DE LEASING LEAS.:000087816520001372 | INTERESES DE LEASING LEAS.:000087816520001372 |
| AMORTIZACION LEASING LEAS.:000087816520001372 | AMORTIZACION LEASING LEAS.:000087816520001372 |
| LEASING-COBRO DEL IVA LEAS.:000087816520001372 | LEASING-COBRO DEL IVA LEAS.:000087816520001372 |
| AN.NOMINAL REMESA EFECTOS ES8230580878030689003155-6030865924 | AN.NOMINAL REMESA EFECTOS ES8230580878030689003155-6030865924 |
| IMPORTE ORDEN PAGO CONTRATO: 000087806860000063 | IMPORTE ORDEN PAGO CONTRATO: 000087806860000063 |

The excepted results should be something like:

| Concepto | ID |
| --- | --- |
| TARJETA ENT: REF:08780807807 8603CDTO. BUSINESS 1040-25/12/2021 | 0878080780725122021 |
| TARJETA ENT:-REF:08780810810 8603CDTO. BUSINESS 1040-25/12/2021 | 0878081081025122021 |
| INTERESES DE PRESTAMO PTMO.:000087816490219968 | 000087816490219968 |
| AMORTIZACION PRESTAMO PTMO.:000087816490219968 | 000087816490219968 |
| INTERESES DE LEASING LEAS.:000087816520001372 | 000087816520001372 |
| AMORTIZACION LEASING LEAS.:000087816520001372 | 000087816520001372 |
| LEASING-COBRO DEL IVA LEAS.:000087816520001372 | 000087816520001372 |
| AN.NOMINAL REMESA EFECTOS ES8230580878030689003155-6030865924 | 6030865924 |
| IMPORTE ORDEN PAGO CONTRATO: 000087806860000063 | 000087806860000063 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please paste sample data as text.

Comment: Is it right now? I'm not really acquainted with this sorry

Comment: Yes, that's better.

Comment: The problem you have is one of logic. What are the rules for extracting ID as I can't see anything consistent. Is it always the set of numbers after a : or -

Comment: Yes, that's it. There are different logics involved in creating this IDs... I don't know whether that's possible or not... 

For instance, if it says "TARJETA ENT: REF:" then it should return the numbers that follow and stop when it says "8603CDTO. BUSINESS". 
If it is PTMO.: then return the numbers...
If it goes on with LEAS.:, again the numbers..

Comment: Your 3 rules you just outlined don't account for AN.NOMINAL REMESA EFECTOS

Comment: Yeah the rule with that it'd be: "AN.NOMINAL REMESA EFECTOS" then 6030865924 in this case, but it can vary.

Comment: As I said, the extraction logic isn't clear or consistent to me. Perhaps someone else will make more sense of it.

Comment: Depending i'd need to use Text.AfterDelimeter or Text.BetweenDelimeter. Might it be possible to put conditions in it? I mean...

Text.BetweenDelimiters([ID], "REF:", "8603") works for the first three "TARJETA ENT: REF"
Text.AfterDelimiter([ID], "PTMO.:"), type text) works for AMORTIZACION PRESTAMO...

Comment: you can look up logic for     if ... then ... else .... and try what you are suggesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are ok with making the ID as just the numbers from `Concepto`:

   ```
   Table.AddColumn(
   ... 
   ,"ID"
   , each Text.Select([Concepto],{"0".."9"})
   )
   ```

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-select
2. If not - seems like you would need to:

   1. [`Text.SplitAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-splitany)on `-`,`:`,`space`
   2. [`List.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-select) items that are (only numbers and >4 characters long) OR (numbers and `/` )
   3. Select number text from those

   ... Which can all be done inside `Table.AddColumn` either as nested function block or an inline function declaration

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, as has been pointed out, is that you are trying to extract data with varying delimiters.

Starting with what you provided, I was able to get to a final data set that I believe is what you are looking for. That said, the caveat is that one step involves removing a specific phrase ("COBRO DEL IVA LEAS."). If that phrase varies, you'll need to find a work around for it.

Here's the M code - the steps can probably be rearranged, but I'll leave that up to you:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "ID", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"ID.1", "ID.2", "ID.3"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"ID.1", type text}, {"ID.2", type text}, {"ID.3", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type","REF","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"ID.2"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","-","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"ID.2"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Replaced Value1", "ID.1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"ID.1.1", "ID.1.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"ID.1.1", type text}, {"ID.1.2", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"ID.1.1"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter2" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns", "ID.3", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"ID.3.1", "ID.3.2"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter2",{{"ID.3.1", type text}, {"ID.3.2", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter3" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type2", "ID.3.1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"ID.3.1.1", "ID.3.1.2", "ID.3.1.3", "ID.3.1.4"}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter3",{"ID.3.1.2", "ID.3.1.3", "ID.3.1.4"}),
    #"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Removed Columns1","/","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"ID.3.2"}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Replaced Value2",{"ID.3.1.1", "ID.3.2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Replaced Value3" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Merged Columns","COBRO DEL IVA LEAS.","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"ID.1.2"}),
    #"Merged Columns1" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Replaced Value3",{"ID.1.2", "ID.2", "Merged"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.1"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Merged Columns1",{{"Merged.1", "ID"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

It produces this table:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|                            Concepto                             |          ID          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| TARJETA ENT: REF:08780807807 8603CDTO. BUSINESS 1040-25/12/2021 |  0878080780725122021 |
| TARJETA ENT:-REF:08780810810 8603CDTO. BUSINESS 1040-25/12/2021 |  0878081081025122021 |
| INTERESES DE PRESTAMO PTMO.:000087816490219968                  |   000087816490219968 |
| AMORTIZACION PRESTAMO PTMO.:000087816490219968                  |   000087816490219968 |
| INTERESES DE LEASING LEAS.:000087816520001372                   |   000087816520001372 |
| AMORTIZACION LEASING LEAS.:000087816520001372                   |   000087816520001372 |
| LEASING-COBRO DEL IVA LEAS.:000087816520001372                  |   000087816520001372 |
| AN.NOMINAL REMESA EFECTOS ES8230580878030689003155-6030865924   |           6030865924 |
| IMPORTE ORDEN PAGO CONTRATO: 000087806860000063                 |   000087806860000063 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

Hope that resolves it for you.

Comment: You are quite welcome. If it works for you, please mark my answer as accepted. Thanks!